# Phonegap Application Fails While Launching

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to this Phonegap, developed small app and configured avd also. When I run the app, it shows the following lines in the console

```
Uploading HcmisAttendance.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-08-28 13:06:39 - HcmisAttendance] Installing HcmisAttendance.apk...
[2014-08-28 13:06:53 - HcmisAttendance] Success!
[2014-08-28 13:06:53 - HcmisAttendance] \HcmisAttendance\bin\HcmisAttendance.apk installed on device
[2014-08-28 13:06:53 - HcmisAttendance] Done!
```

But the problem is application is not opening in avd and my AndroidManifest.xml content is
as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
    <supports-screens
             android:anyDensity="true"
             android:largeScreens="true"
             android:normalScreens="true"
             android:resizeable="true"
             android:smallScreens="true" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  </application>
  <activity  
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</manifest>
```

Please help me to find out the solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot figure out why this happens but when I look at your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, it's mistyped.

Your `Activity` should be defined within the application tags.

`AndroidManifest.xml` should be like following.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <activity  
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Could you please fix that problem and then try to relaunch your application?

Hope this may solve your problem.